# Where should I put a template folder for a bash script?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I'm on OS-X (Mavericks, if that matters), and I'm making a bash script that will use resources from a folder called "templates". I'm trying to figure out where I should put it (the templates folder). I'd like to make it so the user doesn't need to modify their path when they install it, so I'd rather not do it the way the terminal mysql command does it (it lives in a folder in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`). I really want to be able to put them into `usr/bin`, but I don't know if it's "polite" to put folders in there (I don't see any in there).

Right now I'm leaning towards putting the scripts in `usr/bin` and having the templates in `usr/lib`. Is that how this type of thing is normally done, or is there another way? I'd like to follow a convention, assuming there is one. I'd also like it to apply to as many Unix platforms as possible (I'd like to put in a directory where bash scripts live that's consistent across as many Unix platforms as possible). Thanks.

Comment: Are the resources in the `templates` folder executable? If not, why do you expect the user would need to modify `$PATH`?

Comment: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/ but yes, your basic idea about bin for binaries and lib for support files is correct. (You should be in `/usr/local` for local installs, though.)

Comment: @MichaelKropat No, but I would need to modify the path to make the scripts executable if they were stored in /usr/local/myScriptFolder/bin, or /usr/local/myScriptFolder, along with the template folder, correct?

Comment: @tripleee Great resource, thanks.

Comment: The usual way to install binaries is to simply copy yours into `/usr/local/bin` (they can be symlinks if you like) and have a `make uninstall` or similar which knows which ones to remove. This is for system-wide installation; for a personal install, obviously, adding the project's `bin` directory to your `PATH` is acceptable and even recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) (FHS), your executable goes in `/usr/local/bin`, while read-only template files go in `/usr/local/share/YOURAPP/`. To quote [the FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALSHARE1):

> **`/usr/local/share`**
>
> The requirements for the contents of this directory are the same as `/usr/share`. […]

[and](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRSHAREARCHITECTUREINDEPENDENTDATA):

> The `/usr/share` hierarchy is for all **read-only architecture independent data files**.

(Emphasis added)

If the system admin is meant to customize the template files to take effect system-wide, then they would simply go in `/etc/YOURAPP/templates` (or something like that).

If the template files are customized on a per-user basis, then the modified copies of the templates (copied from `/usr/local/share/YOURAPP/templates`) need to be saved in the user's directory, under `$HOME/.config/YOURAPP/templates` or something like that (thanks to **technosaurus** for the correction).

---

You mentioned that you want to install the templates in a directory alongside your executable. That is not the standard approach on UNIX, at least going by the FHS. If you really want to go this route, there is a sort of convention of installing your app to `/opt/YOURAPP/`, using whatever organization you want inside that folder.

In all cases, it is not good practice to install executables directly to `/usr/bin`, as that directory is considered to be under the exclusive control of the OS/distribution. If you want to install there, the accepted way to do that is to create a package for the package manager of every supported OS/distribution.

Comment: If I want the user to be able to edit the template files via the scripts, would they still go in /usr/local/share?

Comment: @Didericis I updated the answer. Admittedly trying to split your files everywhere according to FHS is kind of a pain, so for scripts that aren't widely distributed I might not bother following the standard to the letter.

Comment: There is more specific info at http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html the originals can go in /usr/share but you don't necessarily want each user to be able to edit the templates for everyone (as with /usr/local/share) so saved templates go to $HOME/.config/app_name/template...

Comment: Ooops, I actually cut-pasted the wrong dir.  It should have been $HOME/.local/share (unless it is a configuration file)